# Why does my website redirect from https to http?

Tags: linux, ssl, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, https

I currently created an apache reverse proxy with SSL. During testing, I did this:

`Key in https://10.0.100.100 > browser asks for credentials > I enter credentials > browser goes to http://10.0.100.100 > browser asks for credentials again > I enter credentials again > browser finally shows website, but as http`.

In my CentOS where I created my apache, I created a file called default.conf under the directory "/etc/httpd/conf.d/default.conf" with the following contents:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>

ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyReceiveBufferSize 4096

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / http://intraspace/
ProxyPassReverse / http://intraspace/

#RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
  #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://intraspace/$1 [R,L]

<Location />
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Location>
```

**intraspace** refers to my backend server (the one hidden by my reverse proxy). I commented the rewrite rules because if I realized that if I use them, it will reveal either redirect & reveal my local ip address of my apache (when I type in my public ip of my apache) **or** cause "internal error" when I try any other ip addresses (the backend server ip or the public ip of apache)

How do I resolve this issue of double authentication/redirection, and make my website ip stay at the https version?

Comment: You are redirecting to an http website through the proxypass directive.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably the inraspace is seeing http so returning everything http. If the app handles it you can setup

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
```

Above the proxypass lines and that will tell the backend that ssl has been terminated if the app supports that header